# List files to String array and List files from FTP server

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm writing apllication to synchronize two folders, remote and local, I have idea how doing that. But I'm beginner so, I have a function to listing files in local folder...

```
public static void listLocal(String FTPdirectoryName){
  File directory = new File(FTPdirectoryName);
  File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : fList){
      if (file.isFile()){
          System.out.println(file.getName());
      } else if (file.isDirectory()){
          listLocal(file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
  }
}
```

And,
how can I set the listing files to `String[]`, because i need something like that. And displaying element which I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File directory = new File(FTPdirectoryName);
String[] filesNames = directory.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classic array in this way:

```
public static void listLocal(String FTPdirectoryName){

  String [] clasicArray = new String [100];
  int size = 0;

  File directory = new File(FTPdirectoryName);
  File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : fList){
      if (file.isFile()){
          clasicArray[size] = file.getName();
          size++;
      } else if (file.isDirectory()){
          listLocal(file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
  }
}
```

or java.util.List

```
public static void listLocal(String FTPdirectoryName){

  List<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

  File directory = new File(FTPdirectoryName);
  File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : fList){
      if (file.isFile()){
          collection.add(file.getName());
      } else if (file.isDirectory()){
          listLocal(file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using listLocal method recursively you won't be able to define String array as you don't know that exact size of the array. Better solution will be to use List and define it as class variable so that you can keep adding the filenames in the list when the method is called recursively. But if you still want String array you can convert the List to String array as below.

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

The entire code should look like as below

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //class variable to add file names


public static void listLocal(String FTPdirectoryName){
  File directory = new File(FTPdirectoryName);
  File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : fList){
    if (file.isFile()){
      list.add(file.getName()));  //add file name, should also work for recursive calls as its a member varaible
    } else if (file.isDirectory()){
      listLocal(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }

  String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]); //if you still require string array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable in your class:

```
private List<String> mFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

your method:

```
public static void listLocal(String FTPdirectoryName){
  File directory = new File(FTPdirectoryName);
  File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : fList){
    if (file.isFile()){
       mFileList.add(file.getName()); //.Add files to your collection
    } else if (file.isDirectory()){
      listLocal(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }
}
```